# Multiple routes in Symfony4 result in 404 error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I started a fresh symfony 4.2 website project.

I have created two simple controllers rendering two views.

The first one `localhost/` works fine, however the second one `localhost/home` results in 404 error.

I don't understand what happens, everything is very simple and based on official documentation.

---

**routes.yaml** file:

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\IntroController::introView

home:
    path: /home
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::homeView
```

**IntroController.php** file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class IntroController extends AbstractController
{
    public function introView()
    {
        return $this->render('intro.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php** file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    public function homeView()
    {
        return $this->render('home.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**php bin/console debug:router** command:

```
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path                               
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  _twig_error_test           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
  _profiler_open_file        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                    
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css   
  index                      ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                  
  home                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /home                              
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
```

**apache sites-enabled.conf** file:

```
...
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhostczy
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/czyjestemladna/public

        <Directory /var/www/czyjestemladna/public>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: how about your .htaccess file? it should be configured to point all url into index.php

Comment: @Smankusors Im just trying to find any explaination on how to do this. Not sure where to start. Hope it doesnt break my other projects based on other frameworks on this laptop

Comment: the home.html.twig file is located in templates dir ?also try deleting cache files: rm -r var/cache/*

Comment: @M.Galardi Yes, both twig files are in templates directory. Should I remove /var/cache in project files or in the system? I already used `php bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Just in project. php bin/console cache:clear is Ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forget to install [apache pack](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)?

Try this command inside your project folder

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

This will configure your .htaccess file inside public folder. Basically, when you request `localhost\home`, your Apache will looks at `/var/www/czyjestemladna/public/home`, which don't exist on your computer. So this line from the .htaccess file

```
# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

Will rewrite how Apache access the file, it will now call the index.php instead returning error 404

Comment: Oh well, I have honestly skipped apache-pack installation. I have installed apache2 long time ago and run some other projects that I never finished in Laravel. Was scared to overwrite some configs and lose what I did so far. Is it safe to run this command in this case?

Comment: it should be, if you still worried, just backup the project before running :)